# Visual Studios C# switching between grid controls

Tags: c#, xaml, calculator, visual-studio-sdk

I have begun windows programming and have just completed a functional calculator. I would like to take this calculator further by adding a "Fnc" or "function" button to the user controls which would allow you to view a new set of buttons, but still see the text box with the current entries. I am not sure of how I would complete this using Visual Studios Desktop Edition with Xaml and C#. Could I please get some help?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is by adding another `<Grid>` -or any other container control you see it suitable: `StackPanel`, `WrapPanel`, `DockPanel`, you name it- containing additional buttons. Then you can simply switch the `<Grid>`'s `Visibility` between `Visible` and `Collapsed` upon "function" button clicked.

Comment: If the buttons are not visible will they not be able to function? I guess what I am asking is that the hidden button will not receive a click too @har07

Comment: Yes, hidden button can never receive a click. By using `Collapsed` (not `Hidden`), a control won't even take a space in the UI

Comment: What would the c# code be to cause the Visibility to become Collapsed @har07

Comment: @user3806603 `myGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;`

Comment: so you need the VISIBILITY.Collapsed? I kept trying to do myGrid.Visibility = Collapsed;

Comment: Yes, that's the correct syntax for [enum in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx)